# How can i select item in listView and display the selected item content in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The items in my listView are type string and each item is a full path with a file name.

[image: ListView]

When i click on an item for example the first one i wnt to see the file name content of the item. In this case the Form1.cs content in the directory of it.

The content to load to richTextBox1 i have in the designer.

I did:

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[0]);
            }
        }
```

Trying to read the file name lines and then add it to the richTextbox but maybe first it should not be ReadAllLines but maybe ReadAllText ?

Im both case ReadAllLines or ReadAllText i'm getting error:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string)' has some invalid arguments

And

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to 'string'

Then i tried to add Name property:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[0].Name);
```

But getting error

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ListViewItem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a lot  more information than just the text you're displaying.

You need to access the `Text` property specifically.

```
yourRichTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[0].Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split lines. Lets say your split char **";"**

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[0].Name).Split(";").ToList();
```